# Different Quotation Marks

Tags: ms-word

A quotation mark placed by the Eclipse editor works just fine in an XML file.  Yet if I edit the XML in Microsoft Word and type in a new quotation mark and then place the XML back into Eclipse I get errors.  The two quotation marks look different: one looks normal, while the one from Word looks like an italic version. When I replace the Word Quotation marks with the Eclipse marks the errors go away. I'm sure its different ascii codes.  What's going on here?

Comment: I would recommend against editing any code in Microsoft Word, even if it is just temporary.  Use something like Notepad++ or vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word is inserting smart quotes (that is the technical term for them). The ones that word puts are opening and closing ones. Word is created as a document editor, not a code editor. It puts in corrections to make your documents look better, not preserve language syntax. If you still want to use word as a code editor, you can disable smart quotes (in Word 2007 it is under Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options... > AutoFormat Tab > "Straight quotes" with "smart quotes")

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Word automatically changes quotation marks into curly quotation marks (left and right) as you type. The curly ones are not the same ACSII character as the normal quotation mark.

In Word 2003, there's a setting in AutoCorrect options in the AutoFormat As You Type tab that says replace "straight quotes with smart quotes", so you can disable this feature.  I don't know where to find this setting in later versions of Word.